# I can't update after failed installation of compiz-plugins-unsupported

Tags: compiz, ccsm

I already installed Compiz with extra plugins and followed the forum tutorial on how to install the unsupported Compiz plugins. These are the commands I executed:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa: compiz

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Until here everything worked alright but after entering the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install compiz-fusion-plugins-unsupported
```

I get this error message:

```
Reading package lists ... done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information ... done
E: Unable to locate if the package compiz-fusion-plugins-unsupported
```

How can I fix this, Now I can not update ubuntu with the Software Update Center because I get this message:

```
Failed to download repository information
Do check internet connection (Im Online and my internet conection works all good)
```

These are the details:

```
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/compiz/ppa/...source/Sources 404 Not Found
W: Failed to fetch http :/ / ppa.launchpad.net/compiz/ppa/...amd64/Packages 404 Not Found
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/compiz/ppa/...-i386/Packages 404 Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. Have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

How I can solve this problem?

I would like to either install `compiz-plugins-unsupported` or go back to my previous configuration and be able to update again

Thank you very much in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

please remove this repository because compiz you can found it in default repo so you don't wanna any third party repo

so use this command to remove this repo

sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa: compiz && sudo apt-get update

and to install compiz and all it's package you can do that by search on it and all results  appear to put it in installian command so write that

apt-cache search compiz

and all thing appear write in this command like

[image]

like this

sudo apt-get install compiz compiz-core compiz-dev compiz-dev compiz-fusion-plugins-main compiz-gnome compiz-plugins compiz-pluhins-* compizconfig-settings-manager -y

I'm sorry I have ubuntu 12.04 so I'm not sure if ubuntu 12.10 have same compiz's package but this is very best way to install compiz and you can use my command and see if it sucess or not

Comment: I put to erase the repository:                                   sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa: compiz && sudo apt-get update                                                           But appears me this message:                                   Error: need a repository as argument

Comment: this message appear because the this is wrong syntx of write repo the true repo must be something like this

'sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa' 

as you see repo write without spaces but your repo have space and this wrong so you can open software sources gui and remove this repo of compiz if you found it and then try again to update and install compiz from default repo of your distro

write this to open software sources 

'gksu software-properties-gtk' 

and in tab other software try to find this repo if you found it remove and continue